# How to use a Xtext-based language?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dsl, xtext

I'm new in Eclipse Modeling Project. I need to implement a small DSL using Xtext, so I read the Xtext documentation and try to define my own language. But when I create that I just could use it by running a new instance of Eclipse IDE and I have no idea about using it inside an independent java project or even as a standalone language. So I asked you to share your experience with me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need to implement using Xtext?  Why is Xtext a *requirement*? Have you considered other alternatives?

Comment: Yes. I need it for an university project.

Answer (score 2):

When you are developing the language you can test it by running a new instance of Eclipse IDE.

But you can export your final DSL Plugin as an Eclipse Product. That means you can use it with a standalone RCP application.

This article would be useful to you: [Karsten's Blog](http://kthoms.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/setting-up-a-rcp-product-for-a-dsl/)